# How to check for a one time key up event of key 'down' in Phaser3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a simple requirement. If the `cursors.right` key is released (after pressing down for movement) I'd like to launch an event.

However I can't find a proper function for that. I found `cursors.right.isUp` but this is a boolean and will spam any functionality that is activated by it.

I thought there was an event callback for a one time release like `cursors.right.onRelease('up', callback)` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing key (and mouse) events is something built in in the framework.

You could check the events related to keyboard [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Keyboard.Events.html) or [here](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/keyboardevents/)

Basically you have 3 different events related to `keyup`

On a specific key object.

```js
keyObj.on('up', function(event) { /* ... */ });
```

On a specific key, in an other way.

```js
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-RIGHT', function (event) { /* ... */ });
```

On even on any key

```js
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup', function (event) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Ok that helps somewhat but I need it to work for keyboard events! like left key released. 'pointerup' is referring to mouse pointer events

Comment: Sorry @xetra11 i misread your question, my fault. Answer updated with references to keyboard events.